# What is the countable version of "Run out of something"?

Tags: phrase-request, countable-nouns

It seems like I can only use

> Run out of time.

But how to describe ***there is no more something*** that is countable?

Comment: Think how many distraught nicotine addicts have wailed ***I've run out of cigarettes**!* I don't see what's bothering you about "countable" nouns in such contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: but I can't accept comment as an answer.

Comment: I wasn't trying to answer the question so much as prompt you to explain why you might think "countability" is relevant here. I still have no idea why you think this is an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Run out of time" and "have no time left" would get the same point across, but you're not counting a unit.

An example of this would be "you have five minutes left", but when time runs out you wouldn't usually say "you have no minutes left"

For another example we can use biscuits:

- There are five biscuits left
- There are no biscuits left
- We have run out of biscuits

I hope this helps clarify the usage for you!

Comment: In your final sentence, *cake* is not being used as a countable noun.

Comment: Good point, removing to avoid confusion

Comment: And *we have run out of cakes* if you want to give an actual example of *run out of [countable noun]*. ;) Although I think a different noun, like *cookies* (or even *pieces of cake* or *servings of cake*), would sound a bit more natural.

Comment: It's always a sad day when one runs out of cakes.

Comment: @JasonBassford: There weren't enough written instances to do an NGram comparison chart, but Google Books thinks it has just 3 pages of results for [*run out of **cakes***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22run+out+of+cakes%22). Compared to at least 10 pages for singular [*run out of **cake***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22run+out+of+cake%22). But you wouldn't often *run out of cookie*, even in the US.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I think it's only because it's context-dependent.  Normally one bakes a single cake and serves it out, hopefully not running out of **cake** before running out of *guests*.  But a caterer might have many **cakes**, for a larger event, and may run out of **them** before the evening is out.  Or the cakes might be small, intended for individual consumption.  Which is a roundabout way of saying "cake" and "cakes" refer to different concepts.

Comment: @Andrew: To a first approximation, it's just that people who ***provide*** cakes usually think in terms of (often plural) whole cakes. Whereas people who ***eat*** cake usually don't even eat ***one*** whole cake - they just have ***a slice** [of some yummy uncountable foodstuff].*

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Anyone who eats only a *slice* of cake has more self-control than I do.  Which is why I try not to bake **cake**, because if I bake **a cake**, I eat **a cake**.  :D

Comment: @Andrew: With you all the way! It's no good being asked *Would you like **a chocolate biscuit**?* Obviously if I'm gonna eat them at all, I wanna eat ***a packet** of chocolate digestive biscuits!* Just don't start what you can't finish, is my motto. After all, it would be irritating to have to eat just the few left-over biscuits another day (just enough to get you into stuffing your face again, but not enough to fully satisfy! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers And there is an episode of the TV show *The Magicians* called [*Have You Brought Me Little Cakes?*](https://themagicians.fandom.com/wiki/Have_You_Brought_Me_Little_Cakes%3F) I suppose their plurality and countability is enhanced by their small size . . .

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, I didn't realise you put so much research into your answers! I've updated my answer again based on your feedback. Thanks again!

Comment: I’ve heard people say “you’ve no time left”; so I don’t see why “you have no minutes left” would be improbable, in let’s say, an exam.